# angular 2 RC5 ngModules vs. barrels

Tags: angular, angular-rc5

In our project we are moving from Angular 2 RC4 to RC5.

Question is: with the introduction of ngModules, will the barrels (index files) become unnecessary? 
Or can you use both in parallel? how to use these 2 concepts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Barrels are to simplify **TypeScript** imports and are optional.
They aren't recommended anymore by the Angular2 team because they often cause issues with circular dependencies and similar.

`@NgModule()`s are Angular2 compilation units. `@NgModule()` and are an entirely different and unrelated concept and mandatory.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
If Barrels aren't recommended anymore, what would be a good replacement of this concept?

Comment: Do you have a source for the "not recommended"?. I'd be interested in reading any discussion about this.